# How to read a keyboard inputs on Arduino without a computer, using only digital pins

Tags: arduino

I want to use any conventional keyboard with a usb and 4 wires, I am making something that takes a keyboard input and translates it to a controller output, I have the second part covered but I need a way to read the input of a keyboard using only digital pins. In my ideal scenario I would strip the wires of a usb cable and solder them to jumper wires which I will read from my Arduino.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) only. Your question doesn't include any code yet, just wiring. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a [usb-host shield](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-usb-host-shield). I think there´s also a library to read usb inputs.

Comment: I would have to use a Arduino uno for that which does not have the processor to send controller imports, does the shield include a way to also send signals acting as a keyboard or is it just input?